QGIS - workaround when the intersection tool returns lots of NA when polygons overlap two values in the overlay layer
I've got a large vector layer of 1000s of polygons of a particular habitat in a country, and I need to report on the area of this habitat falling within 20 different regions (I've got a vector layer for this).
I've used the 'intersection' tool in geoprocessing to add the region name to the attribute table of the habitat vector layer, and then I use GroupStats to sum the area of habitat within each region.
This seems to work OK, but the problem I have is that a high proportion of the habitat polygons fall across two regions, and so they get labelled 'NA' by the 'Intersection' tool, and then don't get summed correctly.
Is there any way that the 'intersection' tool (or a similar tool or set of tools) can split polygons that overlap two regions and then label/sum area appropriately?
